# Limit of a sequence bounded by a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sequence of real numbers $\{X_n\}$ such that $|X_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. I want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }X_n=0$. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your definition of a convergent sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard epsilon based convergence argument will work for you here. Don't think of it as being bounded by a convergent sequence. Rather, you've been directly given the fact that the distance between $x_n$ and $0$ goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

To formalize this argument: a sequence $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ converges to a value $x$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that if $n > N$, then $\left| x_n - x \right| < \epsilon$. In this case, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ sufficiently large such that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. And if $n > N$, then $$\left| x_n - 0 \right| = \left| x_n \right| < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>n_0\Rightarrow 1/n<\varepsilon$. By assumption,
$$|X_n|<\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon,\quad \forall n>n_0,$$
which is exactly the definition of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n = 0$.